# Troubleshooting an infinite loop error

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw an array of images on canvas at random x,y but it gives me an infinite loop.... here is my code

```
var fruits = ["fruit1.png", "fruit2.png", "fruit3.png", "fruit4.png"];
var monsterReady1 = true;
var draw = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
        monsterImage1 = new Image();
        monsterImage1.onload = function () {
            monster1.x = (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 100));
            monster1.y = (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 100));
            ctx.drawImage(this, monster1.x, monster1.y);
        };
        monsterImage1.src = fruits[i];
    }
};

var render = function() {
    if (monsterReady1) {
        draw();
    }

    var main = function () {
        update();
        render();
        requestAnimationFrame(main);
    };
```

Comment: Where is `fruits.length` set?

Comment: where is `fruits` defined?

Comment: Don't think that code could produce an infinite loop. Are you 100% sure?

Comment: Whatever `fruits` is, it should not lead to an infinite loop...

Comment: @Alexander Yes but without providing information about it is hard to help with it, correct?

Comment: There is no infinite loop in the code provided, but the definition of `fruits` does not help, either. We need the whole code to locate the infinite loop.

Comment: @Alexander what if `fruits` is object with length property equal to Infinity (of course it is not and the problem is in draw() infinite execution. I just want to say this information is important).

Comment: @magmag your code is ok (http://jsfiddle.net/gn8wv9g7/). pls, show us the call of `draw()` function

Comment: guys the code is updated

Comment: @GlenSwift the code is updated

Comment: @JamesDonnelly monster1 is an object which has x,y are setted to zero

Comment: Having now formatted your code the problem may be clear - are you really declaring `main()` within `render()`?

Comment: You're calling `window.requestAnimationFrame()` inside of `main` and also passing `main` as the `callback`, hence you call `main()` which calls `main()` which calls `main()` and so on

Answer (score 2):

You have recursive in `main()` function. This is normal behaviour of requestAnimationFrame(). It is normal to call that function infinite to draw canvas each frame.

There is also recursion when `render()` executes. You don't need to call render again and again. Pass out render call from `render()` body

```
var render = function(){
    if (monsterReady1) {
        draw();
    }

    var main = function () {
        update();
        render();                            // THIS is error. You should not call render again
        requestAnimationFrame(main);         // This will call main function infinite loop. Expected.
    }   
};

//render();                                    // Better to call it here
```

By the way in code you provide there is a syntax error. You missed one closing bracket